# Telegram video call with USB webcam stream (pytgcalls)

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I'm trying to send the stream of a usb webcam with `pytgcalls` on Telegram. In the [documentation](https://pytgcalls.github.io/) there is nothing about that, but there are several example of streaming youtube video or local mp4 files. I have found this example of streaming a youtube video and I think that streaming a usb webcam is quite similar.
First of all, importing modules:

```py
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client

from pytgcalls import idle
from pytgcalls import PyTgCalls
from pytgcalls import StreamType
from pytgcalls.types.input_stream import AudioImagePiped, AudioVideoPiped
from pytgcalls.types.input_stream.quality import HighQualityVideo, HighQualityAudio, LowQualityAudio, LowQualityVideo
```

Now, start pyrogram and pytgcalls clients:

```py
app = Client('py-tgcalls', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

call_py = PyTgCalls(app)
call_py.start()
```

Declare the function that will convert the youtube link to a stream:

```py
def get_youtube_stream():
    async def run_async():
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            'youtube-dl',
            '-g',
            '-f',
            'best[height<=?720][width<=?1280]',
            # Some random YT link
            'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAAAAAA',
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
        return stdout.decode().split('\n')[0]
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_async())
```

Declare the function for sending the stream via telegram, in a group:

```py
def youtube():
    remote = get_youtube_stream()
    call_py.join_group_call(
        # Group ID
        -10011111111,
        AudioVideoPiped(
            remote,
            HighQualityAudio(),
            HighQualityVideo(),
        ),
        stream_type=StreamType().pulse_stream,
    )
```

Now the function `youtube()` can be executed:

```py
youtube()
```

Using `idle()` for blocking the script:

```py
idle()
```

This is the script, can somebody help me in streaming the live of a usb webcam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently by pytgcalls (0.9.0) was added the possibility to stream from an upd stream, you can use directly ffmpeg to capture the media device and make local UDP streaming

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks! i will try to figure it out how to do this! :) do you have some links that can help me?